# Modifying the debug information of llvm IR

Tags: llvm, debug-symbols, llvm-ir

I want to modify debug information of an llvm instruction so that the 
modified debug info is subsequently passed to executable binary. So if I 
use "addr2line" utility on the binary, it will return my modified debug 
information.

I've tried to change by using the following code snippet:

```
MDNode *N = Inst->getMetadata("dbg");
DebugLoc Loc = DebugLoc::get(newLine, newCol, N);
Inst->setDebugLoc(Loc);
```

I read the DebugLoc back by using

```
const DebugLoc D = Inst->getDebugLoc();
unsigned Line = D.getLine();
outs() << Line <<"\n";
```

But I can't set the debug info correctly. How can I change the debug 
info correctly through llvm pass?

Comment: I'm looking for the same functionality. Did you have any progress on it?